# How do I use intersentence spacing in chapter/section names with hyperref?

Tags: spacing, hyperref, acronyms

I use Vim + vimtex + latexmk + xelatex. When using an acronym in a chapter name, Vim brings up this lint:

```
Intersentence spacing (`\@') should perhaps be used.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{FOO: Bar}
Foo
\end{document}
```

If I use `\@` like so, no lints:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\begin{document}
\chapter{FOO:\@ Bar}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Then `hyperref` complains:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/backref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)) (./foo.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./foo.out)
(./foo.out)
Chapter 1.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\spacefactor' on input line 5.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `\@m' on input line 5.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def) [1] (./foo.aux)
 )
Output written on foo.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on foo.log.
```

So what should I use? Or should I ignore either the `lint` or `hyperref`'s complaints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warnings (not errors) come from the bookmark code. The setting of the space factor by `\@` can be used with TeX, but not in bookmark strings. There the command can be disabled by:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}% option "pdfencoding=auto" or "unicode" recommended
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\@\@empty}
```

Comment: Sigh.. That leads to another lint: `Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names. "\@empty"`.

Comment: @muru You underestimate `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` :-). It supports `@` in macro names, because `\@gobble`, `\@firstofone`, `\@empty` and friends are quite useful here.

Comment: I don't, whoever wrote the linter does. :D Thanks, I think I'll ignore that lint, or find out the issue tracker for it and file a bug.

Comment: @muru if you use `\empty` instead of `\@empty`, that should (I assume) solve the lint issue in this instance (but obviously it would be useful for the linter to recognise the use of internal commands in this context, such as those Heiko mentioned).